# Core Plot - Plot label going beyond boundary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-plot

Am using Core Plot to display a line chart. The label for plot gets cut when it is near (though not outside) the border as seen below

[image]

though, as you can see in the XCode Storyboard (below pic) that the border of each graph is well above (height) and there doesn't seem to be a reason why the label of the plot is getting cut.

[image]

I have set the graph Hosting View's frame to match the frame size in XCode.

```
    self.graphHostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                                   self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHostView.bounds];
```

Also, how do I get rid of the label name in X-Axis (the leftmost 1.0 and rightmost 5.0)?

**EDITED**

@EricSkroch , I tried the following :

*CASE 1*
Setting 
    plotAreaFrame.paddingTop=20.0
    plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=15.0

[image]

*CASE 2*
    graph.paddingTop=20.0
    graph.paddingBottom=15.0
(didn't set anything for plotAreaFrame)

[image]

*CASE 3*
Setting both the above (plotAreaFrame & graph padding)
    plotAreaFrame.paddingTop=20.0
    plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=15.0
    graph.paddingTop=20.0
    graph.paddingBottom=15.0

[image]

*CASE 4*  - Seems to be the best output! (though the top is still cropped)
Setting top padding to 0 for both plotArea & frame
    graph.paddingTop=0.0
    plotAreaFrame.paddingTop=0.0

[image]

*CASE 5*
If I try to increase either plotAreaFrame or graph's top-padding, this is what i get
    graph.paddingTop=5.0

[image]

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? 1.3 was released recently. It fixed some labeling and layout issues from previous versions.

Comment: The version am using, I assume (from Core Plot's plist file) is 1.0. However, it is a few months old one. Let me upgrade, check & get back. Thanks, @Eric !

Comment: @EricSkroch I upgraded to Core Plot 1.3 (the latest from the website). The problem persists. Can you please help?

Comment: @EricSkroch I upgraded to Core Plot 1.3 (the latest from the website). The problem persists. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Add some padding to the graph and/or plot area frame (`paddingLeft`, `paddingRight`, etc.). This will push the plot area in away from the edges of the graph leaving room for the labels.

Comment: let me try. Thank you, @EricSkroch

Comment: I tried what you suggested, in vain. Posted my output for various cases by editing my original question above. Kindly assist.

Comment: It looks like you fixed the axis labels. The plot data labels will get clipped by the plot area, so the only solution there is to expand the plot space `yRange` a little bit to make room for the labels.